# What does type `*` mean for __vfptr?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pointers, visual-studio-debugging

Yes I know * is a pointer.  That's not what I'm talking about.  In one of my programs I had a breakpoint set and I noticed that in the autos there was a variable `__vfptr` with value `0x000007feed210a00`.

However under type, it just said * and that's it.  All of the other pointers in my program had types like `unsigned char*` or `some::namespace::Frame*`, or `int*`.  These make sense since the pointer is tied directly to a particular class or data type.  But I have no idea that the * could be, are there really just plain pointer types?

**EDIT** :   I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Please can you post the exact line of code?

Comment: What debugger do you use?

Comment: `__vfptr` seems to indicate a pointer to a virtual function. Probably the debugger couldn't resolve the exact type there.

Comment: What environment? What debugger? What language was the program written in? _If_ something C-like, the `__` in the variable name would indicate some kind of implementation-internal detail, and a bare `*` could be some abbreviation of `void *` or perhaps some other kind of internal "generic pointer".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`__vfptr` contains the [Virtual method table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) and it contains information that allows  dynamic binding in inheritances.

Information in it will include things like [function pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer) to resolve `virtual functions` and information on the class and it's parents.

Comment: It contains a lot moe than that.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is obviously implementation dependent, and formally concerns your debugger, and not C++.  In practice, however, some variant of `_vptr` is the more or less standard (in the sense usual, and not in the sense of being defined by a formal standard) name for the pointer to the `_vtable`, which in turn contains all sorts of information necessary for the resolution of virtual functions and RTTI.  So the `_vptr` is a pointer to a table of pointers, offsets, and a lot of other different things.  The debugger is probably just avoiding having to give this target a name or describing its structure.